# Find earliest date, but while remaining duplicates in R

Tags: r, date, duplicates

[image]

I need to extract the earliest date of surgery from my file, but if I use the codes I'm used to, it deletes duplicated dates.

For example if a person has 2 different surgeries but at the same date, R deletes one of these surgeries, so I am left with only one of them.

I need to find a solution that can retrieve the earliest date of surgeries, but if one person have two different surgeries at the same time, I would like to keep both dates (which are then duplicates).

"D_ODTO" is the surgery date and "C_OPR" is the surgery type.
"PNR" is ID names.

Comment: Images are not the right way to share data/code. Add them in a reproducible format which is easier to copy. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem, you should be able to do this using functions from the **`tidyverse`** package. Suppose your data is in a data.frame called `d`:

```
library(tidyverse)

d %>%
  group_by(PNR, C_OPR) %>% #group by ID and surgery type
  slice_min(D_ODTO) # find the "min" (i.e. earliest) date
```

As Ronak said, without having a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) I cannot test this code.